# Encode to JavaScript object, function get replaced

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have an issue on highcharts project , charts options are saving in database . I am printing on chart using following code . Let me explain my issue using some sample code .

```
echo 'var options69 = '.$highcharts_json_options;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo 'var options69_func = '. json_encode( $functions);
echo PHP_EOL;

echo '$(document).ready(function() {';
echo PHP_EOL;
echo '      chart69 = new Highcharts.Chart( 
                $.extend(true, options69, options69_func) 
            );';
echo PHP_EOL;
echo '});';
```

The issue is `$functions` not converts into correct JavaScript object . Here is example of code of  $functions

```
$functions = array(
    'chart' => array(
        'events' => array(
            'click' => "function(){inboxMenu(this.options);}"
        )

    ),
    'tooltip' => array(
        'formatter' => "function(){
            return '<b>'+ this.series.name + ':</b>'+ this.y;
        }"
    )
);
```

currently,  `json_encode( $functions)` outputs is

```
var options69_func = {
    "chart": {
        "events": {
            "click": "function(){inboxMenu(this.options);}"
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "formatter": "function(){return '<b>'+ this.series.name + ':<\/b>'+ this.y;}"
    }
}
```

But I need value `var options69_func` is like

```
var options69_func = {
    "chart": {
        "events": {
            "click": function(){
                inboxMenu(this.options);
             }
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "formatter": function(){
            return '<b>'+ this.series.name + ':<\/b>'+ this.y;
        }
    }
}
```

Then only chart `click event` or `formatter`  works .. These values are coming from dynamically from server database . Could I add callback function to `json_encode` ?

I added php generated js code to http://jsfiddle.net/u9W6X/

**I won't like to using eval function.. on client side**

Comment: JSON is not javascript. You can run `eval` on that string to turn it into js

Comment: @DavidFregoli how to make `$functions` array into argument of `eval` function ? recursive loop of associative array  `$functions` ?

Comment: Maybe this link should help you: http://code.dimilow.com/how-to-add-javascript-function-expression-and-php-json_encode/

Answer (score 0):

After you get options69_func,
if you want to excute the function "click",
You can try this:
eval('('+options69_func.tooltip.click+')'+'();');

Comment: I won't like to using eval function.. on client side

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how you can sanitize the JSON.
http://jsfiddle.net/zUEsF/1/

```
var obj = {
"chart": {
    "events": {
        "click": "(function(){inboxMenu(this.options);})"
    }
},
"tooltip": {
    "formatter": "(function(){return '<b>'+ this.series.name + ':<\/b>'+ this.y;})"
}
};

function update( el ) {
var out = {};
$.each(el, function(k, o) {
    if ( (typeof el[k]) === 'object' ) {
        out[k] = update( el[k] );
    } else if ( ( typeof eval(el[k]) ) === 'function' ) {
        out[k] = eval( el[k] );
    } else {
        out[k] = el[k];
    }
});
return out;
};
```

But you have to wrap the anonymous functions with `()`s.

Comment: Sorry, didn't save the fiddle, try now

Comment: I won't like to using eval function.. on client side